# Device almost unusable after Google password change

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, password, google

Today I changed my Google password.  The next time I turn on my tablet I am suddenly confronted with a "Re-type password" screen - yes, it takes the whole screen.  So I jump over to another app to pull the new password from my keychain, but before I can do this, the "Re-type password" screen pops back up.  I literally have 2-3 seconds before it pops up again.  How am I supposed to get my password if it literally won't let me go to any other screen?  How can I disable it long enough to let other apps run?  I have tried the "back" button and I have tried the wrong password just to try to force it to give me a rest, but regardless of whether I tell it to retry, cancel, or just let it sit there asking me, as soon as I switch to another app, a couple seconds later it rudely jumps back to asking me to re-type the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Settings, go to General:Accounts:Google: and then disable everything from being synced.  As soon as this is done, the password prompt will stop popping up.  After password is changed, sync can be enabled again.